# Structure of Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H} = C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathrm{GL}(2, F))$.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field. If $K = \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathcal{O}_{F})$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G = \mathrm{GL}(2, F)$, then we understand the structure of $\mathcal{H}_{K} = C_{c}^{\infty}(K\backslash G/K)$ of $K$-biinvariant compactly supported smooth (i.e. locally constant) functions with convolution well - this is commutative and generated by elements $T(\mathfrak{p}), R(\mathfrak{p})$ and $R(\mathfrak{p})^{-1}$ where $T(\mathfrak{p}^{k})$ is a characteristic function of the set of all $g\in M_{2}(\mathcal{O}_{F})$ such that ideal generated by $\det(g)$ in $\mathcal{O}_{F}$ is $\mathfrak{p}^{k}$, and $R(\mathfrak{p})$ is a characteristic function of the set
$$
K\begin{pmatrix} \varpi &  \\ & \varpi \end{pmatrix} K = K\begin{pmatrix} \varpi &  \\ & \varpi \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also, we know the relations between such generators well.

I want to know if there's any structural theorem of the algebra $C_{c}^{\infty}(G)$ of all compactly supported smooth functions, which obviously contains $\mathcal{H}_K$. 
This is not commutative (right?), and I want to know if there's any known result about generators and relations of the algebra.

Comment: Don't you want to look at $K_n = \ker( GL(2,O_F)\to GL(2,O_F/\mathfrak{p}^n))$ and $C^\infty_c(K_n \setminus G / K_n)$ and the compactly supported distributions on $G$  with projections $\phi \mapsto \frac{1_{K_n}}{\mu(K_n)} \ast \phi \ast \frac{1_{K_n}}{\mu(K_n)}$.

Comment: @reuns Do we also know the structure of $C_{c}^{\infty}(K_n \backslash G / K_n)$?